# How to run cucumber-jvm tests using Gradle

Tags: cucumber, gradle

I am trying to get a project going using the new Cucumber-jvm system and Gradle as my build system.

I have used the example Java code in the GitHub cucumber-jvm project(https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm).

My project is set up in IntelliJ and the IDE is able to run the test.

However, Gradle does not find any tests to run. I know this because I broke the test and Gradle said nothing. It also said nothing when it was working.

The class it is trying to run looks like this:

```
import cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import cucumber.junit.Feature;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@Feature(value = "CarMaintenance.feature")
public class FuelCarTest {
}
```

I'm new to both cucumber and Gradle!!

Comment: You need to provide more information, like the full Gradle build script, your source directory layout, the exact Gradle command you executed, etc.

Answer (score 6):

I remember having trouble with Gradle and Cucumber with the junit runner.
I eventually gave up and created a gradle task using the command line runner.

```
task executeFeatures(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: testClasses) {
    main = "cucumber.cli.Main"
    classpath += files(sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath, file(webAppDir.path + '/WEB-INF/classes'))
    args += [ '-f', 'html:build/reports/cucumber', '-g', 'uk.co.filmtrader', 'src/test/resources/features']
}
```

`-f` Folder for html report output

`-g` Package name for glue/step code

`src/test/resources/features` Where the feature files are

With the following dependencies

```
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5',
            'junit:junit:4.11',
            'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3',
            'info.cukes:cucumber-java:1.0.14',
            'info.cukes:cucumber-junit:1.0.14',
            'info.cukes:cucumber-spring:1.0.14'
```

**Update for version 4.2.5**

There had been some minor changes over time:

- the package name of the cli changed to `cucumber.api.cli.Main`
- The flag `-f` seems no longer to be working and causes an error

So I ended up with the following task definition in my `build.gradle`:

```
task executeFeatures(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: testClasses) {
    main = "cucumber.api.cli.Main"
    classpath += files(sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath)
    args += [ '-g', 'uk.co.filmtrader', 'src/test/resources/features'] 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

other way can be to create a task and include runner class for test

```
build.gradle-
task RunCukesTest(type: Test) << {
include "RunCukesTest.class"
}

testCompile 'io.cucumber:cucumber-java:4.2.0'
testCompile 'io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:4.2.0'


your class - 
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(dryRun = false, strict = true, features = "src/test/resources", glue 
= "com.gradle.featuretests",monochrome = true)
public class RunCukesTest {
}
```

simply hit the command :- gradle RunCukesTest

Answer (score 1):

Considering:

- Your `.feature` files are in `src/test/resources/cucumber/features` and
- your glue classes are in `com.example.myapp.glue`

Then, following what is [explained in the docs](https://cucumber.io/docs/tools/java/#gradle), you can do in `build.gradle`:

```groovy
dependencies {
    // ...
    testImplementation("io.cucumber:cucumber-java:6.2.2")
    testImplementation("io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:6.2.2")
    testImplementation("io.cucumber:cucumber-junit-platform-engine:6.2.2")
}

configurations {
    cucumberRuntime {
        extendsFrom testImplementation
    }
}

// this enables the task `gradle cucumber`
task cucumber() {
    dependsOn assemble, compileTestKotlin
    doLast {
        javaexec {
            main = "io.cucumber.core.cli.Main"
            classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
            args = ['--strict', '--plugin', 'pretty', '--plugin', 'junit:build/test-results/cucumber.xml', '--glue', 'com.example.myapp.glue', 'src/test/resources/cucumber/features']
        }
    }
}

// (OPTIONAL) this makes `gradle test` also include cucumber tests
tasks.test {
    finalizedBy cucumber
}
```

Now `gradle cucumber` will run the cucumber tests.

If you added the last part, `gradle test` will also run cucumber tests.

The `args` part supports what goes in the `@CucumberOptions` annotation of the runner. More details: https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#list-configuration-options

Comment: I put exactly your code, but when sync it tells me that the compileTestKotlin is an unknown property for task ':app:cucumber'. What have you done to make it work?

Comment: @GabrielGarcia Is your gradle a multi-project one? If so, perhaps the `build.gradle` in which you declare the `task cucumber()` matters

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. It is a single app android project build with Kotlin. I included all this in the app module `build.gradle`.

Comment: Ah, ok. Can you instead of `dependsOn assemble, compileTestKotlin` try `dependsOn assemble, testClasses`?

Comment: Nothing. Same error. i am switching into cucumber-android and hope it works